# Spring @Scheduled with cron, how do I handle if the service is down on the scheduled day

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, axon

So suppose I have the system that requires you to add some balance before start using it. So let's say it will deduct/expend your balance on the 30th day every month. So I use **AxonFramework** combine with spring **Scheduled annotation** so the code may looks like this.

```
@CommandHandler
@Scheduled(cron = "** cron for every 30th **")
fun handle(command: ExpendNetflixUserCommand){
  if (user.balance < netflixPackage.price){
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(command.toNetflixUserDisabled())
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient balance, please add.")
  }
  AggregateLifecycle.apply(command.toNetflixUserExpended())
}
```

So my question is if it's on 30th and my system is about to calculate these payment, but suddenly the service is broken/down and it starts working again on 31th will it recalculate the previous payment or not? So if not could you suggest how should I handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider relying on a more full-fledged solution such as [Spring Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html) as you'd get things like job status management pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, I would probably have an external Component annotated with `@Schedule` that will use an instance of a `CommandGateway` to dispatch Commands!
Using this approach, this component is external to your code and bring additional benefits.
One of them is the power to configure a `RetryScheduler` on this `CommandGateway` which will retry failing commands, as you want!

Check the ref guide for more info on how to do it and what implementations Axon offers you out of the box!
https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/implementations#configuring-the-command-gateway